# D3.js: Cannot read property 'getAttribute' of null at Selection.selection_attr [as attr]

Tags: angularjs, d3.js

i am new to D3.js....i am trying to implement a sample chart by following some sample code....i am using d3 version 4.3.0 and i am getting below error

```
ionic.bundle.js:26799 TypeError: Cannot read property 'getAttribute' of null
at Selection.selection_attr [as attr] (d3.js:7705)
at redrawLineChart (controller.js:147)
```

when i  check out the error link it showing this code in my controller

```
function redrawLineChart() {

        setChartParameters();

        svg.selectAll("g.y.axis").call(yAxisGen);

        svg.selectAll("g.x.axis").call(xAxisGen);

        svg.selectAll("."+pathClass)
          .attr({
            d: lineFun(salesDataToPlot)**highlighting this**
          });
      }
```

and in D3.js it showing the below

```
var selection_attr = function(name, value) {
  var fullname = namespace(name);

  if (arguments.length < 2) {
    var node = this.node();
    return fullname.local
        ? node.getAttributeNS(fullname.space, fullname.local)
        : node.getAttribute(fullname);**highlighting this**
  }

  return this.each((value == null
      ? (fullname.local ? attrRemoveNS : attrRemove) : (typeof value === "function"
      ? (fullname.local ? attrFunctionNS : attrFunction)
      : (fullname.local ? attrConstantNS : attrConstant)))(fullname, value));
};
```

Comment: A variation of [*"d3.selectAll to change styles by class in v4"*](/q/38882583). As of v4 you cannot pass an object to `selection.attr`. You need to include the d3-selection-multi module and will then be able to pass that object to `selection.attrs`.

Comment: this is all new to me, i had tried with what ever i know but every time new errors coming by solving one after another.so i reverted back to V3 everything is working fine